# Expressions that mean it's OK to fail or failing is part of success?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, expression-choice

Is there a list of expressions (about 3 words, longer or shorter) that mean "it's OK to fail"?

I'm asking for a list of expressions because I am looking for a domain name and most good domain names are taken.

Thanks.

Comment: [You gotta kiss a lot of frogs](http://www.smartdatingacademy.com/dating-tip-3-sometimes-you-have-to-kiss-a-lot-of-frogs-to-find-your-prince)

Comment: *“up from the ashes” [of failure] come the roses of success*.  It looks like *upfromtheashes.com” is for sale...

Answer (score 1):

)Bounce back

)Don't give up

)Hope springs eternal

)The tortoise always wins

)Do your best!

)Perseverence

)Overcome adversity

)The system screwed you, I'll get my legal team right on it